# How can I pass variables to a new object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, constructor, abstract

I wish to implement [this lib](https://github.com/mrchimp/tock):

```
var timer = new Tock({
      this.callback:  callbackFunction,
      this.interval:  10,
      this.complete:  completeFunction,
});
```

However, I wish to be able to make dynamic calls:

```
var milkshake = my_milkshakes[next];  
var timer = new Tock({
      this.callback:  makeMoreMilkshakes(),  // (Call version 2)
      this.interval:  shakeTime,
      this.complete:  bringThemToTheYard 
});

function bringThemToTheYard(){


    return setNextCallbackFunction();
}
```

The problem here seems to be that I cannot reach outside the scope of the initialization. In Java, I can easily pass arguments to the constructor, except in the case when a function handle is expected.

By abstract I mean that the code is not reusable through reference, but this is admittedly loose terminology.

My goal is to initialize a single `new` timer call to create new timers. I need 5 different timers. Ideally, a single timer would be enough because the timers are started and stopped in linear time.

*My main problem is that I cannot set (for example) `this.interval` to a dynamic variable `x`, because I do not know how to pass a value into the constructor.*

---

My implementation was based on the ["code"](https://github.com/mrchimp/tock) from the documentation below:

```
var timer = new Tock({
  countdown: true,
  interval: 10,
  callback: someCallbackFunction,
  complete: someCompleteFunction
});
```

Comment: 1) Javascript has no notion of "abstract constructors", it's unclear what you mean by that. 2) `this.callback` as a key of an object doesn't make a whole lot of sense, what's that supposed to be? 3) It's unclear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @deceze I have updated my question in response to your comment. Thanks

Comment: ">My goal is to initialize use a single new timer call to create new timers."  So you need a kind of factory function?

Comment: "Abstract" in OOP typically has a very very very different meaning than "in place"; you better avoid the use of this word to reduce confusion. `{ this.callback: .. }` is still a syntax error.

Comment: I'll just reiterate what @deceze said, it's hard to understand what your problem is exactly.

Comment: @lleaff I have considered using a factory pattern, but design patterns are uncharted territory for me. I do not need to add properties, i.e. using prototyping, so maybe I should get back to the drawing board and build a factory.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude or anything but I suggest you go learn a bit how objects and *classes* in JavaScript actually work. It's different to what you may know from Java or C++.

Comment: Regarding your edit: when you do `new Tock({...})`, you are passing a value to the constructor, namely an *object literal* containing various properties. But your object literal is malformed, because the keys can only be string literals, not `this.something`.

Comment: FYI, `someCallbackFunction` *is* a perfectly fine handle on a callback function, **assuming `function someCallbackFunction() { .. }` is declared** within scope! It's not "pseudocode", just the implementation of `someCallbackFunction` is not shown.

Comment: @deceze I have previously tried updating the question in response to your previous feedback. This time, I am not sure I understand. Which scope are you referring to?

Comment: Well, ignore scope for the moment. `function foo() {}; new Tock({ complete: foo });` works just fine is what I'm saying.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not too sure you have a grasp on JavaScript and how much it really differs from Java - they are not that similar.

This:

```
var timer = new Tock({
    this.callback:  makeMoreMilkshakes(),  // (Call version 2)
    this.interval:  shakeTime,
    this.complete:  bringThemToTheYard 
});
```

Doesn't work in JavaScript. That's a syntax error as you can't use dot notation (`.`) on the left-hand side of an object definition. It seems like maybe you want something like:

```
function Tock(config) {
    var defaultCallback = callbackFunction;
    var defaultInterval = 10;
    var defaultComplete = completeFunction;

    this.callback = config.callback || defaultCallback;
    this.interval = config.interval || defaultInterval;
    this.complete = config.complete || defaultComplete;

    /**
     * This could also be written as follows, I just wanted
     * to emphasize how many people write "defaults" in JS
    this.callback = config.callback || callbackFunction;
    this.interval = config.interval || 10;
    this.complete = config.complete || completeFunction;
    */

    // Go on doing stuff....
}

var timer = new Tock({
    callback: makeMoreMilkshakes(),
    interval: shakeTime,
    complete: bringThemToTheYard
});
```

Also, this line looks off:

```
    callback: makeMoreMilkshakes(),
```

This is assigning the *result* of `makeMoreMilkshakes` to the callback, not the function itself. If that's intended, then never mind this bit. But I think you want:

```
    callback: makeMoreMilkshakes,
```

without the `()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I was looking for was this:

```
function startNewTimer(type) {
  var timer = new Tock({});

  var options = null;

  switch (type){
    case "first":
      options.callback = function1;
      options.interval = interval1;
      options.complete = startNewTimer(second);
      break;
    case "second":
      options.callback = function2;
      options.interval = interval2;
      options.complete = startNewTimer(third);
      break;
    case "third":
      options.callback = function3;
      options.interval = interval3;
      options.complete = startNewTimer(fourth);
      break;
    case "fourth":
      options.callback = function4;
      options.interval = interval4;
      options.complete = startNewTimer(first); //Start over from function1
      break;
  }

  timer.callback = options.callback;
  timer.interval = options.interval;
  timer.complete = options.complete;

  timer.start(0);
  out("Starting timer: ".concat(timer.callback));
}
```